# Using unicode characters in Python's command line (Python 3.4.1.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, command, line

I want to develop a Python application (I am using Python 3.4.1.) that deals with logic, and therefore I need to print some Unicode symbols, like the “and” symbol. When I run the program in Python’s shell I don’t have problems printing the characters, but when I try to run it on Python’s command line, this error appears:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02c4' in
>   position 13: character maps to

Do you know if it is possible to print these characters  in the command line?

If it is possible, how can I do it?

Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a small program that can be run and that exhibits this error?

Comment: what is the difference for you between python shell and python command line ? If your code is in a file did you save it using utf-8 ? did you add the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the begin of the file ? Are you on windows or linux ?

Comment: What platform are you on? And, when you say "Python's shell", do you mean IDLE? This looks very much like a case of [Python PrintFails](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails).

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the encoding of the terminal you are using - 
One of the most complete encodings is utf-8, and if you ensure your terminal is
on utf-8 you should have no problem printing these characters.

The "charmap" encoding is used on the windows terminal - and can only didplay a subset of 256 unicode characters - which do not include '\u02c4', among possibly others you might want.

There is nothing you can do on the Python side, but for changing your app to open an application window using Tkinter or another graphic toolkit.

For reference check

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails